# Prevent the use of TouchID registered fingerprint of an unauthized person in my application

Tags: ios, touch-id

If I have a corporate app that we want to use TouchID for but need to prevent unauthorized access in the scenario where staff have a registered fingerprint of another member of their family on their device, what could be done?

Answer (score 2):

What you want isn't supported. The `LAContext` feature that lets your app ask iOS to authorize a user based on fingerprint (or Face ID on an iPhone X) only tells you whether the user successfully provided a valid fingerprint for the device. That's it. There is no way to know who the user is or if even there are multiple users.

If a user has access to the device (fingerprint or passcode), then the user will have access to the app if the app's only security is to use `LAContext`.

Comment: is correct, the only alternative I can think of is a 3rd party biometrics authenticator like Doan: https://www.daon.com/